# How to set stylesheet for the current item in QTableView

Tags: qt, qt5, qtableview, qtstylesheets

When `QTableView` edit control is visible for the current item the shylesheet of the edit takes place. When there is no active edit control in the `QTableView` the current item is styled using the `QTableView { selection-background-color: }` How to set different style only for the current item?

[image: Current item visible only when QTableView has focus]
  [image: Active edit-box on the current item]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Qt style sheets support sub-controls and pseudo states, you can use it to improve your customization. [see Qt6 docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-pseudo-states)

In this case you can use the `::item` sub-control and the `:focus` pseudo state (the "current" pseudo state doesn't exist, but the `:focus` does the same).

This is an example that you can use:

```
QTableView::item:focus
{
   selection-background-color: yellow;
}
```

[image]

See also [Qt6 documentation of customizing a qtableview](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtableview)

Comment: It seems Fabio is the only one who has read the question so far. However this solution may work for QTreeView but unfortunately does not work for QTableView.

Comment: @UgaBuga. What's the problem? Before posting my answer I have tested in a QTableView and it works.

Comment: Fortunately you are right. Your solution works on a blank project. It seems that there is a styling problem in my big project which I should further research.

Comment: However it works for selection but still cannot achieve it only for current item.

Comment: It's very strange, in my table it works as you can see in the picure I've added. In my table this is the only style sheet rule.

Comment: It works but only if the table has focus. When the table loses focus all the selection turns gray and the current item cannot be distinguished.

Comment: How to set background on a specific item.? I mean change background the item in (1,1) position.

Answer (score 1):

**1**. As it IGHOR said you can use data() method in your model and provide a color when role is Qt::BackgroundColor. But there is a stumble here because you don't know whether *index* is current or not. You'll ought to set a current index in the model when it changes and then make a check like this:

```
if (index == m_currentIndex and role==Qt::BackgroundRole) return Qt::black;
```

Actually it's not the best idea to tell the model about currentIndex according to Model/View pattern, because you can have two views for one model.

**2**. Descendants of QAbstractItemView has method setItemDelegate. A delegate is used to draw a cell.
All you need is to inherit from QStyledItemDelegate, pass a pointer to the view to the delegate and override method initStyleOption.
Then do something like this:

```
void MyStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem *option,
   const QModelIndex &index) const
{
  QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(option, index);
  QStyleOptionViewItemV4 *v4 = qstyleoption_cast<QStyleOptionViewItemV4 *>(option);
  if (index == view()->currentIndex())
  {
      v4->backgroundBrush = QBrush(Qt::grey);
  }
}
```

**3**. **If you really need to use css** (for example you have themes) you can do it this way:

Add something like this in your css file:

```
QTableView  
{  
  qproperty-currentItemBackground: #cccccc;  
}
```

Modify *initStyleOption* from the previous example to use the property:

```
v4->backgroundBrush = view()->property("currentItemBackground").toColor();
```

With this approach you can set a specific style via css for a column, a row, a single cell or a group of cells.

Comment: having attempted #3, I would not recommend this approach. Delegates is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new delegate, that renders itself based on the data model (custom role, for example). You need to base its style on a special control created for the purpose (that can be changed via stylesheet) . I'll post some code when I find time.

One can use variadic templates, and crtp (Coplien) to good effect to layer one's delegates