# How to contro QTableView Item's outline

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qtableview

The example-code below creates a `QTableView` linked to an `QAbstractTableModel`.

[image]

The black background is being applied with:

```
p=self.palette()
p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), QtGui.QColor("#0F0F0F"))
self.setPalette(p)
```

Unfortunately there is a white outline/border around each tableview item ("Animals", "Birds" and "Fish").

Question: How to colorize the item's white border?

```
    import sys, os
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)


    class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
        def __init__(self):
            QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)        
            self.items=['Animals','Birds','Fish']

        def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):   
            return len(self.items)
        def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
            return 1

        def data(self, index, role):
            if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)):
                return QtCore.QVariant()

            item=str(self.items[index.row()])

            if role==QtCore.Qt.UserRole:
                return item
            if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                return item
            if role==QtCore.Qt.TextColorRole:
                return QtCore.QVariant(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.white))

        def headerData(self, column, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
            if role!=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:   return QtCore.QVariant()
            if orientation==QtCore.Qt.Horizontal: return QtCore.QVariant('My Column Name') 

    class TableView(QtGui.QTableView):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(TableView, self).__init__(parent)

            self.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Base)

            p=self.palette()
            p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), QtGui.QColor("#0F0F0F"))
            self.setPalette(p)

            myModel=TableModel()
            self.setModel(myModel)       

            self.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
            self.horizontalHeader().setDefaultAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)


    view=TableView()
    view.show()   
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## EDITED LATER:

Here is the working code with the CSS approach implemented:

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)        
        self.items=['Animals','Birds','Fish']

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):   
        return len(self.items)
    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)):
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        item=str(self.items[index.row()])

        if role==QtCore.Qt.UserRole:
            return item
        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return item
        if role==QtCore.Qt.TextColorRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.white))

    def headerData(self, column, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role!=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:   return QtCore.QVariant()
        if orientation==QtCore.Qt.Horizontal: return QtCore.QVariant('My Column Name') 

class TableView(QtGui.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TableView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.horizontalHeader().setDefaultAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)        

        myModel=TableModel()
        self.setModel(myModel)      

        appStyle="""
        QTableView
        {   
            background-color: black;
            gridline-color:black;
            color: black;
            selection-color: black;
        }
        QTableView::item 
        {   
            color: white;
            background:black;            
        }
        QTableView::item:hover
        {   
            color: black;
            background:#ffaa00;            
        }
        QTableView::item:focus
        {   
            color: black;
            background:#0063cd;            
        }        
        """
        self.setStyleSheet(appStyle)

view=TableView()
view.show()   
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt stylesheets are very mighty for styling and I recommend them. With

```
self.setStyleSheet('QTableView::item{background:black;} QTableView{gridline-color:black;}')
```

instead of `setPalette` in your example you achieve black items and black grid lines of the table. You can do much more with style sheets, for example change the background of the item when selected. See the [stylesheet reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html).

Comment: See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23938636/how-to-set-stylesheet-for-the-current-item-in-qtableview for styling the current item.