# Change color of particular QTableView rows with StyleSheets

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on an music application that has a QTableView with a list of tracks. When I select one and hit play, I would like to change its row's color. I know I can do it in the data() function of the model, however the new color to be applied has to be taken out of a style.qss file where the style for the whole application is stored. I read a bit about dynamic properties but I couldn't see how to apply them to specific rows. Is there a class for a QTablewView's item?
If there is I could do something like:

```
MagicItemClass[played="true"] {
background-color: #something
color: #something
}
```

and then use setProperty() and unpolish() and polish() functions.

Another desperate attempt would be to parse the style.qss and get the color and return it in the data() function.

However I really think there must be a better solution.

So do you know of any "MagicItemClass"? Or do you have any other ideas on how to implement this feature?

EDIT:
I saw:
[How to set stylesheet for the current item in QTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23938636/how-to-set-stylesheet-for-the-current-item-in-qtableview)

However this is not the solution I was looking for. This sets only the current row's color. I would like that color to remain even after another one is selected to be played. The new color's whole point is to distinguish played tracks from unplayed more easily.

UPDATE:
Ok. Let me reformulate. I saw the question that was answered. Its solution doesn't work for me. I don't want to change the color of the item in focus. I want it to be permanent. Plus if the user clicks on a row in a table that doesn't mean it's been played(however it is in focus). I saw the pseudo states and couldn't find one that fits(I may need a custom one, is there anything like this?).

Comment: QStyledItemDelegate might work.

Comment: @m.s.
I don't want to set the color just for the current item. The new color must be applied to all rows for tracks that have been played while leaving the other unchanged.

Comment: @Greenflow How should I use QStyledItemDelegate?

Comment: The Qt documentation has a good example. Search for "Star Delegate Example". Your use case is a simpler than that, but should point you in the right direction. QTableView has a function **void QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegateForRow(int row, QAbstractItemDelegate * delegate)**. This should allow you to set your custom delegate for individual rows.

Comment: @Greenflow Ok. Thank you very much for your response! I will try it and come back with the results.

Answer (score 0):

What about setting the desired cells as checked in YourModel::data() function?

```
YourModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) {
   if(role==Qt::CheckStateRole)
   {
      if(alreadySelected(index))//check some QVector of selected indexes..
         return Qt::Checked;
      else 
         return Qt::Unchecked;
   }
   ...
}
```

I am not sure how to write stylesheet for checked.. maybe its something like this

```
QTableView:item:checked {
   background-color: #something
   color: #something
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. I don't know why. I also have some checkboxes in that table but they didn't change their color.
I can't edit your answer but I think it is QTableView::item:checked