# QTreeView custom item display delegate and CSS

Tags: css, qt, delegates, qtreeview

I have a QTreeView displaying my data and I have installed a custom delegate to one of the columns to display a colored progress bar, which appearance depends on the content. I was able to emulate the default delegate behavior using the color information provided by `option.palette`:

```
class ProgressBarDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    ProgressBarDelegate(QObject *parent = 0) {}
    ~ProgressBarDelegate() {}
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
    {
        // QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index); // default implementation

        painter->save();

        // progressbar construction and drawing

        painter->restore();
    }
};
```

Now, I want to highlight a row on mouse hover event. I set a custom CSS to the tree view:

```
ui->treeView->setStyleSheet("QTreeView::item:hover{background-color:#D0E0F0;}");
```

The hover highlighting works, but, expectedly, my custom delegate implementation ignores the CSS setting:

[image: Without defaulte delegate]

(Darkblue line is the selected item, lightblue-ish line is the CSS hover-highlighted line)

Enabling the default implementation allows the CSS setting to affect my delegate, but it messes up the picture:

[image: With default delegate]

The question is:

- Is there any way to know the overriding CSS setting data from withing the delegate? `option.palette` doesn't seem to contain this info.

I have tried reading the QTreeView property as descried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23938636/how-to-set-stylesheet-for-the-current-item-in-qtableview):

```
qDebug() << treeView()->property("background");
```

but the console shows `QVariant(Invalid)`

I also tried reading the Qt source code for `drawControl()` and `drawPrimitive()` methods, which are used in the default delegate implementation, but I managed to find only widget palette references and no connections to the CSS overrides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the [source](http://cep.xray.aps.anl.gov/software/qt4-x11-4.2.2-browser/d6/dbe/qstylesheetstyle_8cpp-source.html) I found out that apparently, there's no way to access the CSS data from within the delegate by default as the CSS parsing and calculations are being handled by a private QStyleSheetStyle object an application doesn't have direct access to. This object simply modifies respective `option.palette` fields to be used by drawing routines.

However, there is a way to force the delegate to draw some of the elements with desired settings without manually parsing the `option.palette` fields by calling the style's `drawPrimitive()` method:

```
// drawing background with desired colors:
option.widget->style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_PanelItemViewItem, &opt, painter);
```

This method will draw the background with respective settings:

[image: somewhat acceptable]

I *think* there should be a similar way to force the CSS-modified setting to be used, something in the lines of:

```
option.widget->style()->proxy()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_PanelItemViewItem, &opt, painter);
```

however, due to lack of understanding of inner workings of Qt's style framework I wasn't able to find it yet.

Answer (score 0):

As you're drawing the component in the `paint` method, you can draw the "hover" effect

You can use something like this:

```
// detect the hover
QStyleOptionViewItemV4 styleOption(option);
bool mouseOver = (styleOption.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver);
// draw if hovered    
if(mouseOver) {
...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was really hoping that I would not need to detect all of the needed states manually. I guess I will have to implement your solution after all.